# Как определить поддержку двух типов для свойства в классе?

Tags: c#

Есть класс:

```
public class Number
{
    public readonly float Value;

    public Number(float value) => Value = value;
}
```

Как добавить возможность создавать экземпляры со свойством Value с типами - int или float ?

Comment: использовать обобщения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Number<TData>
    where TData : unmanaged
{
    public readonly TData Value;

    public Number(TData value) => Value = value;
}

Number<int> dval = new Number<int>(100);
Number<float> fval = new Number<float>(20.3f);
```

Так?

Comment: А зачем нужен констрейнт `unmanaged`?

Comment: Ну, тс просто попросил только для int, fliat, я подумал что класс Number,  ему нужен только для типов unmanaged :)